# Express promise doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

I am quite new in promises and I think I don't understand it correctly because I am trying it in my code without success.

I have a server on NodeJS, using Express library and express-promise

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(require('express-promise')());
```

Then I am handling ajax query:

```
var promise = function() {
    for(var query in req.query ){
        console.log( 'query: ', query );
        switch( query ){
           case 'getobserved':
             results.observedTags = getObserved();
             break; 
           ...
        }
    }
};
```

And getObserved is getting data from Firebase DB

```
var getObserved = function() {
    var observedTags = dbRef.child('observedTags');
    observedTags.on('value', function(snap) {
        var allObservedItems = snap.val();
        var list = [];
        for(var ii in allObservedItems ){
            list.push( allObservedItems[ii].name );
        }
        return list;
    });
};
```

And finally I am trying to send response to client by:

```
promise.then( res.send( results ), someRejectedMethod );
```

And I get in console this:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at d:\wamp\www\soz2\server.js:100:13
```

Probably method "promise" is undefined. I am not sure if I use express-promise wrong, or it's just my lack of knowledge about whole promises. Need some hint, please

Comment: You're defining `promise` to just be a regular anonymous function.  Something isn't a promise just because you named it `promise`.  Therefore, the `then` property is undefined.

Comment: Ok I understand, but can you give me a hint, what should I do ?

Comment: Sorry, it isn't clear me to what you are trying to do.

Comment: trying to send response to user when my function 'promise' will be finished;

Comment: You don't need a promise for that.  At the end of your function, simply call `res.send()`.  If you have straightforward logic and want to do something at the end of a function, a promise doesn't help you with anything.

Comment: @PiotrWójcik: Please show us the complete method `promise`. What asynchronous things are you trying to do there, whose "finish" you want to await?

Comment: I am getting data from Firebase DB, I updated post with proper code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Probably method "promise" is undefined.

No, the `promise` function seems to be defined. Only it is a function, not a promise object, and has no `.then` method.

> I am not sure if I use express-promise wrong

Yes. From how I understand [their docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-promise), all it seems to do is make `res.send`, `res.json`,  and `res.render` accept promises or objects that contain promises, which are then recursively expanded and awaited.

> or it's just my lack of knowledge about whole promises.

That as well. I recommend the [general promise resources](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/General-Promise-Resources) as an entry point to learn about promises.

First, you will have to [promisify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) your Firebase methods so that `getObserved` does return a promise. (Currently, it seems to fail because you try to [`return` from an async callback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/1048572)). You'll probably have to choose a promise libary if you aren't already using one.

Then, in your route you can use it like

```
for (var query in req.query) {
    console.log('query: ', query);
    switch(query) {
        case 'getobserved':
            results.observedTags = getObserved(); // a promise
            break; 
         …
    }
}
res.json( result ); // here, express-promise does some magic
```

No need for the `var promise = function() {` line. And you probably can scrap `promise.then( res.send( results ), someRejectedMethod );` as well, as express-promise does handle this for you. If you didn't use it, you could have done it explicitly with something like

```
var promise = getObserved();
promise.then(function(list) {
    res.json({observedTags: list});
}, someRejectedMethod);
```